# Vertical align text within a responsive box doesn't work

Tags: html, css

How do I vertical align the text within a responsive box? I did for the image but it doesn't work for span, not sure why. Below is my half way done demo :

```css
img{
    width:20px;
}

div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ddd;
    padding:10px;
}

img{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/256/football.png"/>
    <span>football</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
img{
    width:20px;
    padding:2px;
}

div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ddd;
    padding:10px;
}

img,span{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    float: left;
}
```

**[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/n7La0gec/1/)**

Comment: I am glad this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
span{
 line-height:100px; /* same as parent elements's height */
}
img{
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    /* remove transform */  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `line-height：100px;` property to the parent div element , and remove img's css settings:

```css
img{
    width:20px;
}

div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ddd;
    padding:10px;
    line-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/256/football.png"/>
    <span>football</span>
</div>
```

For only one line text , if the parent's `height` is equal to `line-height`, the inner context element will be vertical align.See [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in multiple ways

**1. You can give the `line-height` to the `span` same as the `height` of the parent div. So in your case, it should be**

```
span {line-height: 100px;}
```

**2. You can make the parent `div` as `display: table` and the span as `display: table-cell`. Then give `vertical-align: middle` to it.**

```
div {display: table;}
span {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```